# Hostname doesn't resolve

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2, ip, ubuntu-10.04, hostname

Alright, so this is a hostname issue.  I have a server setup on my College's network (which is allowed).  The hostname is "moria.student.rit.edu".  The IP address assigned to it is a roamer, and it may change.  Currently, it is 129.21.125.240.

So, everyone /at/ my RIT is able to type in the hostname and visit the website.  However, people outside of RIT are not able to type in the hostname.  In order to visit the website, you need to type in the IP Address.  This makes me think that it is a DNS issue.  This makes sense, because RIT has their own DNS servers, so obviously people on campus (using the RIT DNS servers) would be able to resolve the hostname.  Those people not on campus use a different DNS server, which doesn't know how to resolve the hostname.

My question is this:  Is their an effective way to "push out" my hostname, so that all DNS servers will know how to resolve it, and I don't need to hand out my IP (which may change)?

Running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, using Apache2 as my webserver.

Edit:  It seems that it may be resolving fine for some people.  If it doesn't resolve for some other people, could it be that THEIR DNS is bad, and they should switch?

Comment: Your moria.student.rit.edu resolves ok for me

Comment: Likewise and I'm currently resolving that address to 129.21.125.240 via T-Mobile in The Netherlands so I'd guess that it's mostly OK. TTL is set to an hour so it should update reasonably quickly.

Comment: DNS changes are not instant. It can take several days for a change to propagate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can still visit your site (moria.student.rit.edu). After a change in your DNS settings, it can take up to 48 hours before it's propagated through all DNS servers.

```
$ host moria.student.rit.edu
moria.student.rit.edu has address 129.21.125.240
```

Answer (score 0):

In case that you are on dhcp and the ip changes you 
can use dyndns.org.

Ask the network admin if the dns names given are
available public and not just in the campus network.